# Log out of app with cURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, devise, logout

We have a web app built in Ruby on Rails that uses Devise for logging in and out.  I'm responsible for a backend XML API using cURL.  Users can log in, send updates, etc. at a command prompt with cURL and XML strings, but I don't see how to allow them to log off with a cURL command.

The UI has a logout link that sends a DELETE command, but it uses an authenticity_token parameter that I'm not sure how to emulate or pass through cURL.  The output from rake routes shows destroy_user_session as a DELETE action sent to devise, and I've tried using cURL just to point to its path, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Most of the related resources I've found seem specific to php or to slightly different scenarios.

Edit:  Would it be easier to create a new controller action to handle this, so the user just puts in the correct path, and the actual DELETE/POST/whatever is handled in code?

Answer (score 1):

If you not particular about the delete attribute being present. You can configure in devise to log out via post or get.

in the config/initializers/devise.rb you will find

```
config.sign_out_via = :delete
```

change that to

```
config.sign_out_via = :get
```

Now you should be able to log_out by sending a curl request to the the logout url.

Though my personal suggestion is to authenticate the XML API using key rather than login in using the username and password.

This article should help you get started. http://blog.joshsoftware.com/2011/12/23/designing-rails-api-using-rabl-and-devise/

Comment: I don't mind using DELETE, I just don't know how to make it work.  Is it not possible just to send the correct request to the server with cURL?